# Implementing global monitor for exclusive access

Tags: arm, atomic, memory-barriers, lock-free, load-link-store-conditional

Am implementing a global monitor for exclusive access (for ARM cores).

**Query**- `if a particular exclusive transaction is successful, should I signal a clear on the global monitor?`

In the case above is required, a concern is this would cause other cores which are in the WFE state to be unnecessarily woken up, even if they have nothing to do with a different core's successful exclusive transaction.

Comment: My information is for an ARM32 core.  There maybe different behaviour for an ARM64 core.  I have not used events nor monitors on an ARM64 system.  Please tag appropriately and add information to your question.  It is quite possible that the 32 and 64 behaviour is the  same.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - `WFE` is wait for event.  Events and the global monitor are different orthogonal concepts.  They have synergy when used together, but are completely seperate.

---

> Query- if a particular exclusive transaction is successful, should I signal a clear on the global monitor?

No, this case is successful and the global monitor is automatically cleared.  The 'WFE' is different from the global monitor for exclusive access.  The `SEV` is send an event.  It is not the global monitor.

To clear the global monitor, it is `clrex`.  A `ldrex` reserves the global monitor and an `strex` commits the global monitor if successful.  The monitor itself is on the ''global'' state of memory.  Each CPU/core can have different working copies of the memory to update.  Normally, the `strex` will fail if another core has reserved and committed the same memory.  It is normal to re-issue an `ldrex` to retrieve the updated memory copy when `strex` fails.

An issue comes when a core supports pre-emption and/or interrupts.  One context on the core may issue an `ldrex` and then be pre-empted by a successful `ldrex/strex` pair.  When the context returns, the prior `ldrex` is not reserving anything and the `strex` is undefined.  In this case, the OS (or interrupt code) must issue a `clrex` to force the original paired `strex` to fail and retry. For a Cortex-M, the system often does an intrinsic `clrex` on a return from interrupt, but you need to read your system documentation. For some Cortex-A systems, you need a `clrex` (and the same for normal/secure worlds).

What is your use case for using `WFE/SEV` with the `ldrex/strex`?  I think it needs to be a simple flag as oppose to some lock free data structure.  I guess the WFE/SEV could augment the plain `ldrex/strex` for fairness between cores.

Specifically, it is valuable for a semaphore (simple flag).  The 'semTake()' will do a `WFE` to sleep when it fails.  The 'semGive()' will issue a `SEV` to wake all sleepers in a 'semTake()'.  If a core has gained access to the semaphore, having the other cores sleep will result in a faster `ldrex/strex` to put the semaphore to it's free state as well as save power on the blocked cores. (Rosetta, vxWorks/Posix: `semGive`/`sem_post`, `semTake`/`sem_wait`.  The vxWorks names seem best for a binary semaphore or mutex depending on pendatics... but these are the ARM primitives).